# Root Path in Fast API behind ALB

Tags: python, reverse-proxy, fastapi, aws-application-load-balancer

I am deploying a fast API app behind AWS ALB, with listener rule path pattern `/api/v1/` points towards fast API. My app looks like this

```py
from typing import Union
import os
import mysql.connector
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    print("Root path hit")
    return {"App": "Fargate"}


@app.get("/api/v1/")
def read_apiv1():
    print("Root path hit")
    return {"App": "Path Fargate API v1"}
```

I deployed the app in ECS using docker and my docker run command is

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--proxy-headers", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80", "--root-path", "/api/v1"]
```

Now when I hit my AWS ALB dns suffixed with `/api/v1/` I see the endpoint `/api/v1` which throws the response `{"App": "Path Fargate API v1"}`. However, based on the [documentation from fast API](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/) it should load the api endpoint with `/`.

Can anyone help me why I am getting this unexpected behavior? Do I have to manually write `/api/v1` before all of my endpoints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a proxy with a stripped path prefix, in this case, means that you could declare a path at `/app` in your code, but then, you add a layer on top (the proxy) that would put your FastAPI application under a path like `/api/v1`.

In this case, the original path `/` would actually be served at `/api/v1`.

Even though all your code is written assuming there's just `/`.

And the proxy would be "stripping" the path prefix on the fly before transmitting the request to Uvicorn, keep your application convinced that it is serving at `/`, so that you don't have to update all your code to include the prefix `/api/v1`.

Reference: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/?h=root_#proxy-with-a-stripped-path-prefix

#### About `root_path`

Have in mind that the server (Uvicorn) won't use that `root_path` for anything else than passing it to the app.

But if you go with your browser to http://127.0.0.1:8000/app you will see the normal response:

```
{
    "message": "Hello World",
    "root_path": "/api/v1"
}
```

So, it won't expect to be accessed at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/app`.

Uvicorn will expect the proxy to access Uvicorn at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app`, and then it would be the proxy's responsibility to add the extra `/api/v1` prefix on top.

Comment: cloudfront doesn't strip

Answer (score 5):

This is how I added `/api/v1` to all my routes:

```
from sys import prefix
from typing import Union
import os
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter

app = FastAPI()

prefix_router = APIRouter(prefix="/api/v1")

@prefix_router.get("/")
def read_root():
    print("Root path hit")
    return {"App": "Fargate"}


@prefix_router.get("/something/")
def read_apiv1():
    print("Root path hit")
    return {"App": "Path Fargate API v1"}

app.include_router(prefix_router)
```

After this when I go to `http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/something/` path it automatically redirects me to the second route.

Comment: did you manage to set the prefix for the OpenAPI endpoint as well?

Comment: You can do that using the `openapi_url` parameters of the `FastAPI` constructor

Comment: Just to emphasize (after much frustration :() : The call to `include_router` _must_ come after all of the routes have been set with the @prefix_router decorators. Otherwise it's all 404. Hence at the end of the file like in Hussain's example